# Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable

Tags: javascript

please why is my browser showing this error below and how do i resolve it?

Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: Does your server handle MIME types? How's your script loaded? Javascripts won't run unless they're loaded with the right MIME type, `application/javascript` or equivalent. You may need to show some code here if you want a specific answer.

Comment: Thank you...got it resolved already

Answer (score 0):

Go into http://127.0.0.1:5500/ and check if its actually giving you a JavaScript file or an html/json. It's probably not.

Answer (score 0):

You have *something* trying to execute some JavaScript by requesting that URL, and the response it is getting is an HTML document. Since this isn't JavaScript, you get an error.

Quite likely you have `<script src=""></script>` somewhere in the HTML document you are loading from that URL. The relative URL "" resolves to the *same* URL, which is (obviously) your HTML document again and not some JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. Please kindly go through my code.

```js
// This code should be put in a separate file named "scripts.js"
console.log("Hello");
```

```html
// This code should be put in a separate file named "index.html"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 id="heading"> Welcome to My Website </h1>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// This code should be put in a separate file named "scripts.js"
console.log("Hello");
```

```html
// This code should be put in a separate file named "index.html"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 id="heading"> Welcome to My Website </h1>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).